# Can't enter text on a Mac in a Silverlight text box

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have written a Silverlight C# program.

When I try to use it in google chrome on a Mac it wont let me type in the text box. I can go into the text box but not type anything. On all other computers this seems to work fine. It even works ok in chrome on a pc.

I know this is a Microsoft bug however their solution doesn't work.
I have tried altering the html object for the Silverlight application to be `windowless` with no success and I'm struggling to find the `PreTranslateMessage` in WebViewer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS for the Mac, link the Microsoft solution, give us example code that we can compile and test ourselves.

Comment: Hi I was working with Mike on this - He is now in hospital for a couple of days - nothing serious just unexpected - can I help out - do you want the whole VS2010 sln to have a look at? - The MC OS is Lion 10.7 the browser was safari - However I have tested it on Lion 10.73 and I only get that behaviour on Chrome. It seems erratic - I note in May 2011 there were many posts about not being able to type into a Sivlerlight App and it was regarded as a bug but I cannot find any conclusions - Another similar post was made on Microsoft connect in Dec 2011 n- no response

Comment: A lot of first time posters don't give enough info.  What should be tried is a small silverlight app that has a single text box.  If that doesn't work, then post that here, so others can verify/help.  If it does work, then its on your end.  He says its a Microsoft issue, but if it is only Chrome that it doesn't work on, then it sounds more like a Google issue.

Comment: appreciate those pointers Chuck - tx - the odd thing is another test reports teh opposite on Lion - works on Chrome but not on Firefox - so sounds more like our code - I've no doubt a simple text box will work fine (I will do it nonetheless) - thats murphy's law - Have you any suggestions as to what to look for in the bigger project which might cause this behaviour - we are stumped

Comment: Sorry I've never written a Silverlight app, good luck though

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem and it appears that is at least in part because Silverlight is not supported on Chrome on a Mac.  See system requirements tab on Microsoft's site [here](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx?reason=unsupportedbrowser#).  I've been unable thus far to find any workaround.

Comment: Workaround that works for me is using another browser like Firefox or Safari.